# Dismiss Android Soft Keyboard when changing Tabs

Tags: android

I'm using a TabHost in my Android Application. When a user changes to a certain tab, I would like to dismiss the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you Tried:

To turn on:

```
inputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To turn off

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService)).ToggleSoftInput(ShowShoftInputFlags.None, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would make the answer even better.